# how to append a character in WHERE clause of SQL query?

Tags: sql

I need a query like below,

> select * from table1 where usr_id = user-id + '#' (i.e. if user-id is
>   1234, then value to be validated is '1234#')

Please let me know how to do this in SQL?

Comment: Which is your database? SQL server, Oracle, MySql etc? and what's the data type of user-id column?

Comment: What version of sql? How are you executing this statement?

Comment: From where will you pass the user-id# like 1234 ? Using parameters?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you want to concatenate two strings. The way to do it depend on your DBMS:

```
-- SQL Server / Microsoft Access
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE usr_id = user-id + '#'

-- Oracle
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE usr_id = user-id || '#'

-- MySQL
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE usr_id = CONCAT(user-id, '#')
```

Reference : [SQL CONCATENATE (appending strings to one another)](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-CONCATENATE-24.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE usr_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @ID) + '#'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE REPLACE(usr_id , '#', '') = @ID
```